# Jump to Reference (J2R) Imputation with only Baseline for R

Tags: r, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

I have a data set with baseline and t1 values in an RCT. Is a [Jump to Reference (J2R) imputation](https://thestatsgeek.com/2020/05/06/reference-based-imputation-for-continuous-missing-data-in-r-with-bootstrap-inference/) possible here? The implementations I have found so far all require t2 values next to t1, which I do not have in this case. J2R seams to be  preferred by the drug approval authority.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I'm currently having the same problem.

Comment: no unfortunately not but it is good to know that I am not alone with the question